# What is checkSumAdjustment in TTF/OTF head table used for?

Tags: c, truetype, specifications, opentype

The specifications for [TrueType](https://developer.apple.com/fonts/TrueType-Reference-Manual/RM06/Chap6head.html) and [OpenType](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/otspec/otff.htm#otttables) specify a checkSumAdjustment in the 'head' or 'bhed' table of an Sfnt. Both specifications describe how to calculate this value but I can't find any information on why this value exists and what it is used for.

Bonus question: Why do I have to subtract from 0xB1B0AFBA?

Comment: It's just a checksum-of-checksums. The original TTF file format dates back to a time where bits were lost in transmission more often than not. (It's also an easy way to prevent noobs and hex editors to inject their own name into copyrighted fonts.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The point of this value is to allow font engines to detect corruption in the font without actually having to parse all the font data first. Ideally, the checksum would be all the way at the start of the file, but thanks to needing to unify various font formats, isn't. Instead it's in the head table. Silly, but we're stuck with it.

Each table in a font has its own checksum value, so that the engine can verify that parts of a font are correct "as is", but to make things easier the font itself also has a master checksum that's even easier to compute (find its value offset in the byte stream by parsing a minimal amount of data, then sum the entire bytestream as LONGs while treating the four bytes where this checksum is located as 0x00000000) and can be used to determine whether the font followed the OpenType spec when it was encoded without needing to look up what every table says its checksum is, where it starts, how long it is, and then running the same checksum computation several times for different parts of the byte stream. If the master checksum fails, it doesn't even matter if the checksums for individual tables turn out to be correct: there's something wonky about this font.

The subtraction from 0xB1B0AFBA is pretty much just "for historical reasons" because OpenType unified several specs, rather than starting from scratch, so there's some baggage from older formats left in it (the "OS/2" table, for instance, is a general metadata table and has nothing to do with the [OS/2 (Warp)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS/2) operating system anymore, nor has it for a very long time).

Answer (score 1):

The checksum adjustment field ensures that all truetype/opentype files have an overall checksum of `0xB1B0AFBA`.
I assume this was done so that you can (weakly) validate the file by comparing its checksum to this fixed value, rather than having to read the expected value from within the font.

The reason this works is: By calculating the sum with checksumAdjustment set to 0, then storing `N − old_sum` in that field, the final sum becomes `old_sum + (N − old_sum)`, which is always `N`.
I don't know why they chose `0xB1B0AFBA` in particular, though.

The checksum algorithm is listed here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/otff#calculating-checksums

Here is a working implementation which doesn't rely on endianness:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    uint32_t sum = 0;
    int step = 3;
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) >= 0)
        sum += c << (step-- & 3)*8;

    printf("sum: %#8.8x\n", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In a way, the checksumAdjustment field doesn't really /do/ anything, it's just a convenient place where you can put 4 arbitrary bytes which are needed to manipulate the checksum. but, you could instead add junk data to some other location, e.g. by adding an entry to the `name` table, etc.

Comment: also note that the checksumAdjustment will (regardless of its actual value) automatically *become correct* once you add that junk data. as long as the overall checksum of the font is `0xB1B0AFBA`